# Polynomial coefficients type

Tags: polynomials

To be more accurate, the following is my question:
If we have 2 polynomials $f$ and $g$, where $f\in\mathbb Z[X], g\in\mathbb Z[X]$ and $g$ divides $f$ and let $h$ be their division quotient ($f=g×h$). Let $n$ be the degree of $f$, $p$ be the degree of $g$ and $n-p$ be the degree of $h$, and the quantifiers of $g$: $b_0, b_1,...,b_{p}$ have the greatest common divisor 1.
That being said, are we sure or not of the polynomial $h$ having integer coefficients? If yes, then how do I prove it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with multinomial coefficients; I am removing that tag.

Comment: Do you know[ [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) or related results?

Comment: $g$ divides $f$ in what ring? $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

Comment: @Jens Render it devides it in any ring.

Comment: @Anonymus Then your question is trivial, if $g$ divides $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ where $f=gh$ then $h\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ by definition of 'divides'